# Python Polars find the length of a string in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to count the number of letters in a string in Polars.
I could probably just use an apply method and get the `len(Name)`.
However, I was wondering if there is a polars specific method?

```
import polars as pl

mydf = pl.DataFrame(
    {"start_date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"],
     "Name": ["John", "Joe", "James"]})

print(mydf)

│start_date  ┆ Name  │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ str   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-02 ┆ John  │
│ 2020-01-03 ┆ Joe   │
│ 2020-01-04 ┆ James │
```

In the end John would have 5, Joe would be 3 and James would be 5

I thought something like below might work based on the Pandas equivalent

```
# Assume that its a Pandas Dataframe
mydf['count'] = mydf ['Name'].str.len()

# Polars equivalent - ERRORs
mydf = mydf.with_columns(
        pl.col('Name').str.len().alias('count')
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

- `.str.lengths()` that counts *number of bytes* in the UTF8 string ([doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.lengths.html)) - **faster**
- `.str.n_chars()` that counts *number of characters* ([doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.n_chars.html))

```py
mydf.with_columns([
    pl.col("Name").str.lengths().alias("len")
])
```

```
┌────────────┬───────┬─────┐
│ start_date ┆ Name  ┆ len │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str        ┆ str   ┆ u32 │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ 2020-01-02 ┆ John  ┆ 4   │
│ 2020-01-03 ┆ Joe   ┆ 3   │
│ 2020-01-04 ┆ James ┆ 5   │
└────────────┴───────┴─────┘
```